# Working Precision in nonlinear control systems

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, control-systems

When simulating a nonlinear control system using `StateResponse` , do the options `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal`, and `AccuracyGoal` work as in `NDSolve`? (They should, I think, but I tried and didn't see any difference in precision or computation time.)

Comment: Does this work: Method -> {"NDSolve", WorkingPrecision -> ...}

Comment: It definitely has the effect of changing the computation time! That gives me a tool to find what what kind of error is still going on. Thanks!

Comment: There are no documented options for `StateResponse`.

Comment: I'd thought it was my personal ignorance ;-) Well, declaring "Method" seems to have an effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question with some promising discussion in comments; I'll summarize what was said for future reference, so your question shows up as answered.

[m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) reported that unfortunately there are no documented options for `StateResponse` yet.

However, [Suba Thomas](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5998/suba-thomas) suggested that you can try to pass options to the underlying `NDSolve` by including them in a `Method` statement of the form:

```
Method -> {"NDSolve", WorkingPrecision -> ...}
```

OP reports that this has a definite effect on the computation time, so it is at least promising as an exploratory tool.